# mutidimension array with muti dimension data types in c

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, queue, structure

I have to implement a strange data structure. There is a queue, which contains memory allocations(it may be a queue or array but no-Linked list or anything that use malloc() in the code).
and we have to use this body:-

```
Struct  //we don't have to use pointer in structure in achieving the task
{
int frequency;
unsigned char symbol;
short int left,right;     
}
```

Here you can see that we have alphabets like a,b,c,d and e at the first index and their corresponding frequency on second index and the other two index are not useful for the moment but we have to allocate memory for them right now.

For now only thing which is useful for us is just the second index (which is the frequency of alphabets). What i have to do in this question is two add the two minimum frequency (i have to to put that it at a place so that increasing order must be maintained) for example: You can see below we add first two nodes frequency: So for the first index we obtained result of "a+b",Lets say "z"(a+b=z) and for second index(3+3=6) and the other two index are "0" and"0" , so not useful for us. and we have to now adjust this obtained memory such that it maintains increasing order of frequency

Now question is :
(1) Any ideas how to implement this type of data structure ? (without using pointer,malloc() , linked lists etc.) (but can use queue/stack), Moreover we can use memcpy() for shifts.
(2) How to achieve sorting in this type of case (but it's secondary thing , first how to implement it ?)  (I am sorry i am tagging this question at the topics which could make the solution of this question, sorry for this)
And please do not hesitate me to ask if you don't understand anything in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this structure primarily being used for searching or for storing?  Are you going to be constantly adding and removing elements, or is it going to stay fairly static?

Assuming I understand the problem (which is *not* guaranteed), it sounds like the *simplest* approach would be to use a regular array of your `struct` type<sup>1</sup>:

```
struct afreq {
  int freq;
  unsigned char sym;      // why unsigned? why not just plain char?
  short int left,right;
};

...
struct afreq data[N]; // where N is large enough for as many elements
                      // as you need
size_t dataSize;
```

Use the `qsort` library function to order your array as necessary.  You'll have to write a comparison function to pass to `qsort`:

```
int cmpAfreq( const void *lhs, const void *rhs )
{
  const struct afreq *l = lhs;
  const struct afreq *r = rhs;

  if ( l->freq < r->freq ) return -1;
  if ( l->freq > r->freq ) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

So, assuming you start out with something like the following:

```
struct afreq data[N] = { {3, 'a', 0, 0 }, {3, 'b', 0, 0}, {4, 'c', 0, 0 },
                         {6, 'd', 0, 0 }, {9, 'e', 0, 0} };
size_t dataSize = 5;
```

you could add a new element like so:

```
struct afreq newItem;
newItem.freq = data[i].freq + data[j].freq;
newItem.sym = 'z';
newItem.left = newItem.right = 0;

if ( dataSize < N )
{
  data[dataSize++] = newItem;
  qsort( data, dataSize, sizeof data[0], cmpAfreq );
}
else
{
  // data array is full, can't add another element
}
```

To remove an element from the array, you could overwrite the element to be removed with the last element, reduce the counter by 1, and re-sort the array:

```
data[i] = data[dataSize--];
qsort( data, dataSize, sizeof data[0], cmpAfreq );
```

This is by no means *efficient*; having to fully re-sort the array every time you add or remove data will be expensive (especially since `qsort`'s performance is poor on already-mostly-sorted arrays).  But this is probably the most straightforward implementation I can think of.

---

<sup>1.  Actually, it sounds like the *simplest* approach would be to use a language like C++ or Java or Python or just about anything else that provides a `map` or similar container, keyed on your `sym` member</sup>

Comment: Since he can't use malloc, I assume he is embedded or similar, in which case higher level/interpreted languages are likely out of the question.

Comment: @John Bode actually i don't have to delete any thing .I have to increase the size of memory block keeping all the previous elements as well the one obtained by addition of two minimum elements (I just have to adjust the newly obtained element by making shifts of the elements in the right of the position where newly obtained element is set. In our case "a,3,0,0" "b,3,0,0" will remain at it's place whereas "c,6,0,0" and it's right part will shift by 1 position.Do uoi have solution for it?

Comment: qsort will handle that for you - pass it the array and the comparison function, it will move the elements around the array as needed.

Comment: @GreenAsJade yOU ARE RIGHT but you know i don't have to delete any memory in array(even i have to add one memory for each addition), Ok i explaining:(i only take frequency for the moment to explain) : i have : 3,3,4,6,9 i add two nodes but i have to keep in memory the the two added nodes as well, which are 3+3 here, so the next execution must give me: 3,3,4,6,6,9 (see here we are keeping in memory the first 3,3 and added 1 more memory for the result obtained by addition of 3,3=6).so when i apply qsort again on the same array it will again find the minimum two (which are again 3,3)that repeats

Comment: @user3085082: That's why I added the `dataSize` variable; it tells you how many elements in the array are in use.

Comment: @JohnBode but how to skip the first two element from being the part of sorting and atthe same time we have to also keep them in array ? How to do that? i am still unable to do.

Comment: @user3085082: You could do something like the following: `qsort( data+2, dataSize-2, sizeof data[0], cmpAfreq );`  This will ignore the first two elements in the array while sorting the rest of it.  Although, now that I think of it, this is not going to be the right approach.

Comment: @JohnBode Thanks for the help.Now i have done it, but i am not able to understand that why you have done this "if( dataSize < N )". i have succesfully done it just by reading at index ; i=i+2; and j=j+1 for first and second element and it's working as expected. But anyways it was a big help from you. thanks again.(but if we make difference of "datasize" which is assigned "5" then the output will be wrong, i have dealed with only "i" and "j" index and it's working for me :) )

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might as well declare an array of 26 of your structs, because it appears that you can only have one entry for each letter, no more

```
struct counting_thing //we don't have to use pointer in structure in achieving the task
{
int freq;
unsigned char sym;
short int left,right;     
}

struct counting_thing ordered_things[25];    // one entry for each letter [a-z]
```

Then, you simply need a sorting algorithm that operates on an array of nodes and uses the freq element of each node as the basis of comparision.